# Better Distinguish Greek \Sigma and math \sum?

Tags: fonts, math-operators, greek, math-fonts

I need to use both `\Sigma` and `\sum` in an article, and realize they are so close (except for their size) that they can be confusing for the reader.

I have looked at alternatives for `\Sigma` ideally, or eventually for `\sum`, but haven't found much. The nice [survey](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) by S Hartke shows that for most fonts, they are very similar.

Any recommendations on how to make the distinction between `\Sigma` and `sum` clearer?

Thanks!

Comment: is it really confusing? I cant think I have ever read a summation and wondered if in context that is a a sigma and not a summation. Even if you did `$\Sigma_0^n x^i$` it's pretty obviously a summation even using exactly the sigma glyph.

Answer (score 6):

First off, I will assume that you'll agree with the proposition that there's *no chance whatsoever* for anyone to confuse `\Sigma` with `\displaystyle\sum`. (If this assumption is incorrect, please let me know.)

[image]

Second, I'd say that there are in fact *two* major differences between `\Sigma` and the inline-math (aka text-style) version of `sum`: (a) size and (b) placement. The letter `\Sigma` gets placed on the baseline (as all other letters do too), whereas the symbol `\sum` is centered vertically on the mathline. (What is the mathline, you may ask. In most math fonts, the `=` ("equal") symbol bisects the mathline, while the horizontal portions of `-` ("minus") and `+` ("plus") as well as the three dots generated by `\cdots` rest *on* the mathline.)

I still don't see how any kind of serious confusion could arise between `\Sigma` and `\sum`.

[image]

Third, confusion *could* indeed arise if one were to take a summation over items labelled `\Sigma_1`, `\Sigma_2`, etc. E.g.,

[image]

I hope you will agree that in such a case, the only sensible adjustment has got to be switching from `\Sigma` to some other character, be it Greek (say, `\sigma`), Roman (say, `S`), or anything else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\Sigma \displaystyle\sum$

\medskip
$\Xi\Phi\Psi\Omega\Sigma \sum$

\medskip
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i = \cdots$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the argument is less "it might be impossible to figure out which is meant" and more "it might trip up the reader's cognitive flow to see even superficially similar symbols used with different meanings"; even if a reader can recover from that disrupted flow by trivial reasoning, then the flow has still been disrupted.  I think that the question is therefore sensible (though the scope of its answer is probably outside of a forum on TeX).

Comment: @LSpice - If the main argument truly is ""it might trip up the reader's cognitive flow to see even superficially similar symbols used with different meanings", then the only sensible solution is avoid having these superficially similar symbols anywhere near each other. For sure, it's certainly the main reason for my earlier recommendation to never write `\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i = \cdots$`.

Comment: If you're worried about similar symbols being used with different meanings, then I would suggest avoiding physics. But actually, the sum symbol literally is a sigma, so I too can't really see how this could cause any more confusion than the base level of confusion we have all chosen to accept by doing mathematics in the first place, where letters are constantly being used to mean things they didn't mean.

Comment: @Hakanai - Why did you post this comment below my answer instead of below the original query? What part of my answer are you qualifying, critiquing, supporting, or otherwise addressing? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have been an @ in it. I was referencing @LSpice's reply above.